# Active Collab API doesn't show all reports

Tags: api, report, activecollab

I'm fetching all the open reports tagged as CHECKPOINT using the collab [API](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/reports-and-filters/assignments-filter.html) and it's working fine. Although, when I run a custom report for the tasks, at Active Collab website, I get more and different results than what I fetched.
What I need is to get exactly the same results shown when running a custom report. Does anyone know how can I fix it or if it's a problem with the API itself?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, not as an edit.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open browser console and see which requests ActiveCollab's web interface is making when making fetching data to build a report. Compre this with requests that you are making and see where the differences are.

Web interface gets served by the same API as your app is, so both can be made to work the same. As long as they are making the same requests, as same users.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

By creating a [data filter](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/reports-and-filters/assignments-filter.html), it shows all the reports if `"include_all_projects": true`! Simple is that